# Are AWS API Gateway routes "discoverable"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Or to put it another way:

Should I consider my list API routes public?

Reason for asking is if I setup a web hook for a payment service - will this be available to anyone to post to?

I guess the thing to do would be restrict to their origin.

Comment: You should not rely on security through obscurity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

There are tools like gobuster (https://www.kali.org/tools/gobuster/) which will try to brute-force resources on your api to see what is available.

Rather make sure to secure the webhook endpoint by some other means than obscurity (i.e. by requiring some kind of Authentication and then authorize or deny access based on the authentication results).

Comment: You should probably add an API key to those routes, and configure the payment service to include the key in the requests. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-setup-api-key-with-restapi.html